# How to prevent foreach loop to not remove duplicates

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

this is my json code

```
[{"name":"Lahore","code":"LHE"},{"name":"Rawalpindi","code":"RWP"},{"name":"Wah Cantt","code":"RWP"}]
```

and this is my php code

```
$city_result = '[{"name":"Lahore","code":"LHE"},{"name":"Rawalpindi","code":"RWP"},{"name":"Wah Cantt","code":"RWP"}]';

$cityList = [];
$cities = (array)json_decode($city_result,1);
foreach ($cities as $city) {
    $cityList[$city['code']] = $city['name'];   
}

echo json_encode($cityList,true);
```

when I echo the result is

```
{"LHE":"Lahore","RWP":"Wah Cantt"}
```

It removes Rawalpindi from the list. The code of both Rawalpindi and Wah Cantt is RWP. I want to return both the cities.
Need help.

Comment: Using those codes as keys is not possible because they aren't unique. The answer given shows a reasonable alternative, but if you don't want to do it that way, the root problem remains. The same key will refer to two different values. How will the resulting JSON be used? Maybe we can suggest another solution for that.

Answer (score 2):

You currently have a 1-to-1 mapping between a city's code and its name and there can only be one such mapping for each code.

Looks like you want to have a 1-to-n mapping instead, using arrays (note the additional `[]` within your loop, which append the current value):

```
$city_result = '[{"name":"Lahore","code":"LHE"},{"name":"Rawalpindi","code":"RWP"},{"name":"Wah Cantt","code":"RWP"}]';

$cityList = [];
$cities = (array)json_decode($city_result,1);
foreach ($cities as $city) {
    $cityList[$city['code']][] = $city['name'];   
}

echo json_encode($cityList,true);
```

Output:

```
{"LHE":["Lahore"],"RWP":["Rawalpindi","Wah Cantt"]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I want out should be like:
{"LHE":"Lahore","RWP":"Rawalpindi","RWP":"Wah Cantt"}

Comment: We cannot have more than one items with same key in array.. one way is to suffix or prefix some dummy value like RWP_1, RWP_2 etc and then when you want to see key refer string part which is before _. @HannahJames