# How to prevent foreach loop exclude result from php array

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

this is my code

```
$city_result = '[{"id":"1","name":"Lahore","code":"LHE"},{"id":"2","name":"Rawalpindi","code":"RWP"},{"id":"3","name":"Wah Cantt","code":"RWP"}]';

$cityList = [];
$cities = (array)json_decode($city_result,1);
foreach ($cities as $city) {
    $cityList[$city['code']] = $city['name'];   
}

echo json_encode($cityList,true);
```

The echo return this

```
{"LHE":"Lahore","RWP":"Wah Cantt"}
```

The result exclude the city Rawalpindi. I want to result should be

```
{"LHE":"Lahore","RWP":"Rawalpindi","RWP":"Wah Cantt"}
```

Please help

Comment: You can't have values in array with same keys. `$cityList['RWP']` will return what?

Comment: Isn't this the same as your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68289457/how-to-prevent-foreach-loop-to-not-remove-duplicates

Comment: @NigelRen, no sir, the json is different is previous question.

Comment: @u_mulder is there is any way to achieve the result ? I have option to add anything in json

Comment: Your result will not be parsed corerctly by any json parser. See example: https://3v4l.org/7tacr "Rawalpindi" value __is lost__.

Comment: You can achieve this by having same key for both values.

$city_result = '[{"id":"1","name":"Lahore","code":"LHE"},{"id":"2","name":"Rawalpindi","code":"RWP"},{"id":"3","name":"Wah Cantt","code":"RWP"}]';

$cityList = [];
$cities = (array)json_decode($city_result,1);
foreach ($cities as $city) {
    $cityList[$city['code']][] = $city['name'];   
}

echo json_encode($cityList,true);